# Why does a cross domain request work in Chrome but fail in Firefox when requesting from a Node (Express) server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, cross-domain, express

Some set up information: We're using jQuery for AJAX (and other things, but AJAX relates to this question), Node w/ Express for the server, and Chrome 17/Firefox 10 for testing (we don't need compatibility with IE).

The issue we're running into is a failure to get a response when making a cross domain request to a Node server. For development purposes (and also because we have to run Apache in addition to this server for now) we're running the node server on port 3001 (localhost:3001) which, even on localhost, is considered cross domain by the browser (at least in my experience trying to get two servers on localhost to talk to each other).

I have the `app.enable("jsonp callback")` set up on the server which works wonderfully for our `GET` routes, however it doesn't seem to work so well for our `POST` routes (this is all in house right now, but better alternatives are welcome as suggestions).

The route in question is defined as follows:

```
app.post("/create", function(req, res) {
  // Added the next 3 lines as a test and it seemed to add success, 
  // not happy with it though
  var ref = req.header("Referer");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ref);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  console.log(req.body); // echo request body
  res.json({success: true}); // return a notification of success
});
```

The AJAX request looks like:

```
// The URL is either the IP of the server or Localhost
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3001/create",
  data: { 
    name: "john" 
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  type: "POST", 
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(r) {
    console.log(r);
  },
  error = function() {
    alert("Failed");
  }
};
```

Some minor information, when we use the above in Firefox with `dataType: "jsonp"` it simply fails with a `404`, but actually sends the request with just `"json"`. Another bit of information is that without `crossDomain: true` the request doesn't work at all. The Firefox requests made with the above actually go through to the server, however it errors out before receiving the response.

The request works fine and succeeds in Chrome, however fails in Firefox. According to the console the response returns a status of "200 OK" but it still fires the jQuery.ajax error function with a `statusCode` of `0` and a `statusText` of `Error` (which is very helpful...) and despite what we've tried we've not made any progress as to making this work.

Any help or direction in where to go to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Just for the sake of updating. This problem has stopped occurring, perhaps it was some underlying error in our code we fixed in a refactor without realizing it or it was bug in Firefox that has been fixed. Either way we no longer encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to do `JSONP` style callbacks, you need two things: `app.enable("jsonp callback")` (not `app.enable("json callback")`). Also, you need to indicate to jQuery to do a JSONP call by specifying `callback=?` in the URL.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is `jsonp callback`, I copied that over incorrectly (but corrected it now). Also, if I tell jQuery to do straight `"jsonp"` requests it doesn't work at all - as a matter of fact, it ignores the POST entirely and only sends GET requests. However, with the `crossDomain: true` and using `dataType: "json"` the request works. That's not my real question anyways, the question is why does it work in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Comment: Just for sake of trying I attempted to implement your proposed solution but it began barking with 404 not found - as opposed to my above usage where the response goes through and returns a "200 OK" but still fails in Firefox (not Chrome).